# The correctness of use the word type to refer to some language element

Tags: rust, types

When we have some struct `T`, we usually refer to `T` as a type.

```
pub struct Player;
```

and we can say, the `type player`.

But what if it's a trait instead?

```
pub trait Player {}
```

is correct to refer to the trait player with the word `type`? Or they have another nomenclature, word or similar?

What about the `enumerated types`? Is that correct?

```
pub enum Player {
    Soccer,
    Rugby,
    Basket
}
```

where we can refer to the enum as *the enumerated type Player*, or just *the type player*.

Comment: A trait is not a type, so you shouldn't use the word type for it, but rather call it, well, "trait". An enum type is a type, so feel free to call it as such.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think this question is "opinion-based", since there can't really be different opinions about what a type is in Rust. But then again, I'm not sure I fully understand what this question is about.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks. I guess your first comment asks well my question. Explaining it better and shorter? The correctness of call "type" to some typed element of the language could be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) (emphasis mine),

> In computer science and computer programming, a data type (or simply type) is **a set of possible values** and a set of allowed operations on it.

As traits don't contain values it is incorrect to call them types. As enums do it is correct to do so.